# Using SED to extract and delete a particular line from a set of similar instances in a file

Tags: sed

I have one text file as below :

```
[groups]
grp = john, perk, honda, choco, dough
devops = john, honda, perk

[repository:/]
@devops = r
john = rw
honda = r
dough = r

[demo:/]
@grp = r
dough = rw
```

Here I want to remove a string based on the first word search i.e. I want to remove "dough = rw" line from demo ([demo:/] ) block. It should not remove dough from repository( [repository:/] )block.

I am able to fetch demo block with below command :

```
sed '/\<demo\>/,/^$/!d' a.txt
```

But in the same command I want to remove dough line in the text file specific to demo block without removing the dough in [repository:/] block.

Comment: You almost have it! Just put a delete instead of not delete on a match of dough after the demo paragraph match: `sed '/\<demo\>/,/^$/{/dough/d}'`

Answer (score 0):

The command you used for printing the demo block is the right way. You can use the same addresses: `/\<demo\>/,/^$/`; it means "between `demo` and an empty line". But the action won't be `!d`, don't delete, but "remove dough":

```
sed -e '/\[demo:\/\]/,/^$/{/^dough =/d}' a.txt
```

I changed the first address to `\[demo:\/\]` so the command works correctly even if there's a user named `demo` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\[/h;G;/^\[demo:/M{/dough = rw/d};P;d' file
```

This saves each section in the hold space and then appends it to each line. The address is then checked to see if it is part of the `demo` section and if that line contains `dough = rw` it is deleted. Otherwise the line is printed and then deleted along with the section info.